# ResponseReceived data type in WAI

Tags: haskell

I wonder, why WAI's `Aplication` type is designed as `Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`. Why not `Request -> (Response -> IO ()) -> IO ()`? The docs say

> A special datatype to indicate that the WAI handler has received the response. This is to avoid the need for Rank2Types in the definition of Application.
>
> It is highly advised that only WAI handlers import and use the data constructor for this data type.

How this special datatype helps to avoid `Rank2Types`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Application` should really be

```
type Application = Request -> (forall b. (Response -> IO b) -> IO b)
-- a.k.a. Request -> Codensity IO Response
-- newtype Codensity f a = Codensity { runCodensity :: forall b. (a -> f b) -> f b }
-- which is closely related to continuations
```

That is, an `Application` takes a `Request`, a function `f`, and it calls `f` with a `Response`.

```
app :: Application
app req f = f _resp
```

`Application` *forces* you to call `f`. There is no other function capable of producing an `IO b` inside `app` except for `f`, so, since `app` must produce an `IO b`, `app` must call `f`. `wai` depends on `app` calling `f`, and it could enforce it with this `Application`. However, `Application` is higher-ranked, which is somewhat undesirable.

The solution actually used is:

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
-- a.k.a. Request -> ContT ResponseReceived IO Response
-- in general, ContT is "bigger" and "weaker" than Codensity
-- but, in exchange, does not require higher ranked types

app :: Application
app req f = f _resp
```

`f` is still the only thing `app` has on hand that can produce a `ResponseReceived`, as long as `app` doesn't break the contract it has with `wai` and import the constructor. You can't replace `ResponseReceived` with `()`. Everyone and their mother has the constructor (`()`) for `()` available. I don't think it's even possible to *not* have it. This makes it unsuitable for `Application`:

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ()) -> IO ()
app :: Application
app _ _ = return () -- uh oh
```

Comment: Do you mean `type Application = Request -> (forall b. (Response -> IO b)) -> IO b` ?  I think the final paren may not be where you intend.

Comment: No, I meant what I said. See [the history of `wai`](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/commit/1e1b8c222cce96c3d58cd27318922c318642050d). The type you gave is invalid. `b` is out of scope in the final `IO b`.

Comment: Thank you for such an exhaustive answer.